# Proof that composite function does not exist.

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I have two functions:

$$f:\{x \in \mathbb{Z}:x > 5\} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 2^x - 70$$
$$g:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{Z}, g(x) = 3x + 7$$

Show that $fg$ does not exist.

The problem is that my proof shows that $fg$ exists. Here is my proof.

1. $R_g = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}:x>7\}$
2. $D_f = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}:x > 5\}$
3. Since $R_g \subset D_f \implies$ $fg$ exists.

Is there any way that I could have left something out? Thanks. What is a better way to prove this?

Comment: How $g$ has image in $\mathbb{Z}$? $g(0.5)= 3*0.5+7$ is not an integer

Comment: I thought that $g:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{Z}$ means that all images other than integer images are rejected. Am I wrong in my understanding of notation?

Comment: Is it possible that the exercise is not well written? I mean, $g$ is not well-defined because of the fact that its image is not integer. But the image of $f$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$, as you can see. And now one can think of the composite $gf$. Now, what is the range of $f$? 
This is the only way I see to make sense of this exercise

Comment: That is a possible cause of confusion. The range of $g$ is not defined properly. But say I tweak the question a bit instead and define $g$ as $g:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, would the result be the same since the domain of f is as stated?

Comment: In this case the range of $g$ is not contained in the domain of $f$, and one cannot talk of composite function $fg$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is not well-defined. $x\in(0,\infty)$ does not guarantee $3x+7\in\mathbb{Z}$. For example, $\pi\in(0,\infty)$ but $3(\pi)+7\notin\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I show this though - could I write that $g$ is not well-defined.

Comment: If $g$ is not well-defined, $fg$ cannot be well-defined.

Comment: My understanding of the notation is totally off. What does $g:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{Z}$ mean? Does it mean that all images that are not in $\mathbb{Z}$ are rejected?

Comment: The domain of $g$ is $(0,\infty)$. So the range of $g$ should be a set containing all possible values of $3x+7$ when $x\in(0,\infty)$. If you can find a positive real number $x$ such that $3x+7$ is not an integer, then $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be the range.

Comment: Can I say that the range of $g$ should be $\mathbb{R}$ in that case?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ can be the range. If range means codomain, it can be any set that contains all possible $g(x)$. So $\mathbb{C}$ is also a possible range. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)